# Law of cosines in double pendulum

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics

I can't yet explain why equation (8) at [Double Pendulum](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DoublePendulum.html) implies that the square of the magnitude of $\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2}$ (where $\vec{v_1}=l_1\dot{\theta_1}\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\vec{v_2}=l_1\dot{\theta_2}\hat{\theta}_2$) is $v_1^2+v_2^2+2v_1v_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ instead of $v_1^2+v_2^2-2v_1v_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$, which should be the case by the law of cosines. How can this be explained?

Comment: That's not what they are doing at all. You have to compute $v_1^2$ and $v_2^2$ separately. $\frac{1}{2}m_1l_1^2\dot\theta_1^2$ is the KE of the first bob, everything else is the KE of the second bob.

Comment: Bob 1 has velocity $l_1 \dot{\theta_1}$. Bob 2 has velocity magniture of $\lVert l_1 \dot{\theta_1}\hat{\theta_1} + l_2 \dot{\theta_2}\hat{\theta_2}\rVert$. To combine these two vectors, we can use the law of cosines.

Comment: I'm not sure how you computed the velocity magnitude of Bob 2, but leaving that aside for now, why are you computing the magnitude of the sum of the vectors? Their masses are different, so you can't combine them together anyway

Comment: We are not concerned with masses when we need to compute velocities. So we add the magnitude of the velocity of the 1st bob and the magnitude of the velocity of the 2nd bob (relative to the pivot of the 2nd bob, of course, which is at the tip of the first bob). If you don't agree, then please let me know how you explain this equation.

Comment: I see, I mistook the $v_1$ and $v_2$ with the ones in the original article. Well, I'm not entirely convinced that the angle between the two velocities is given by $\theta_1-\theta_2$.

Comment: It is $\theta_1-\theta_2$ because $\vec{v_2}$ is directed at angle $\theta_2$ relative to the vertical and $\vec{v_1}$ is directed at angle $\theta_1$. Hence the difference. It is easier to see if you draw a picture with $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ attached to the second bob.

Comment: Okay let us call the velocity of the first bob relative to the origin $v_1$, that of the second bob $v_2$, and the relative velocity of bob 2 to be $v_{\text{rel}}$. So we have: $\vec{v_2} = \vec{v_1}+\vec{v_{\text{rel}}}$. If you draw it out and label the angles, you'll see that the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$ is $\cos(\pi-\theta_2+\theta_1)$. This rearranges to $\color{red}{-}\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

Comment: Why do you consider the angle between $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ rather than the angle between $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_{rel}}$? $\vec{v_2}$ is the sum of $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_{rel}}$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant to say the angle between $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_\text{rel}}$. The result still stands though.

Comment: Cross-posted to [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293284/law-of-cosines-in-double-pendulum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual formulation of the Law of Cosines, in the formula 
$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta,$
the angle $\theta$ is the *interior* angle opposite side $c$.
But in this question, the angle $\theta_1-\theta_2$ is the *exterior* angle of the relevant triangle. Its cosine is equal in magnitude to the cosine of the interior angle, but has the opposite sign. 
If you let $\theta=\pi-(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ then $\theta$ is the interior angle opposite the resultant vector when you construct a triangle for the sum of the two velocity vectors, $\cos\theta=-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2),$ and the formula with $\cos\theta$ will have the sign you expected.

If you still doubt the formula, try it with some simple numbers. Let $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$. 
Then the velocity of the second mass at that instant will be $l_1\dot\theta_1+l_2\dot\theta_2$, and $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)=1$. You should find the formula in the question gives the correct kinetic energy at that instant.